# greatest cardinality set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which one set has the greatest cardinality?

A) reals
B) maps from the integers to the integers
C) maps from the reals to {0,1}
D) all the finite subsets of the reals
E) all the polynomials with coefficients in the reals

I would pick C because I see that D and E have the same and C is the greatest among the first three? But couldn't come up with a rigorous argument. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herein we'll use the equations $2\aleph_0=\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0,\,2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=c\aleph_0=c,\,c^2=c$. In particular$$2^{\aleph_0}\le\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0},\,c^2=\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^2=2^{2\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=c.$$

A has cardinality $c$, B has cardinality $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=c$, C has cardinality $2^c>c$ by Cantor's theorem, D has cardinality $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c^n=c\aleph_0=c$, and so does $E$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain a bit about B and the first equality of D please?

Comment: @stevengerrard See edit.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I actually asked about the cardinality equality. Do you have like a list of cardinality equations? I am not sure actually how the equality holds. I understand how you get the LHS of the equality. Thank you!

Comment: @stevengerrard See edit.